# How to test System.Web.Configuration.AuthorizationSection?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

In my web config I am only allowing users in a specific Active Directory group access to a directory

```
<location path="Administration">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="MyDomain\MyApp-Administrators"/>
      <deny users="?"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

I have links to pages in that directory, which I would like to disable on my web pages.

In code, in my page_load, I am able to retreive the section of the web.config:

```
System.Web.Configuration.AuthorizationSection authorization = (System.Web.Configuration.AuthorizationSection)System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/authorization", "Administration");
```

I could probably roll my own logic to example the configuration and determine if the current user still has access, but I run the risk of my logic not matching how the framework does it, or introducing other bugs.  Is there existing functionality I can use to tell me if a user would have access to a page within my applicaiton, at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar for a file-viewer tree tool that seeks out a web.config in each directory/sub-directory and checks to see if the user has access to that folder, in a function that returns a bool. I think the part that may work for you is:

```
foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in authorization.Rules)
{
    if (rule.Action == AuthorizationRuleAction.Allow)
    {
        foreach (string role in rule.Roles)
        {
            if (Roles.IsUserInRole(role)) //This would be whatever Role management you are using to check if the logged-in user is in a role.... so should be the same as how the framework does it.
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
     }
 }
 return false;
```

This has worked nicely for me:

1. It uses the role management function to see if they have access (I use a custom function and don't [Roles.IsUserInRole()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.isuserinrole.aspx), so just use whatever the site normally uses to control access based on roles).
2. It uses the web.config value so nothing is hard coded.